# Getting a filter based on if task is done or not in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a page that displays a list of tasks and when your done with those tasks you can then click on them and say that they are complete.
The way I've done it is that there is a database that saves a timestamp (under 'done' in the table) of when that task was done and what I would like is to filter those that 
is or isn't null.

For example: If I click on 'Done' then only the tasks with a timestamp is shown and if I click on 'Not Done' then the tasks that has a value of null is shown

Here is my code

```
    <template>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item" @click="isPending()">Not Done</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item" @click="isCompleted()">Completed</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-sm mt-2">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th> </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="task in tasks" :class="{isPending}">
                                    <td>
                                        {{task.description}}
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right" @click="completeTask(task.id)">Done</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    tasks: [],
                    isPending: false,
                }
            },

            computed: {

            },

            methods: {
                isCompleted(){
                    let complete = this.tasks.find(t => t.completed !== null);

                    this.isPending = true;


                }
            },

            mounted() {

            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: so the table should only display incomplete tasks? where is the Not Done button?

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed properties as values in your template, so write a script like this:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
   tasks: [],
   showDone: false
  }),

  computed: {
    getTasks() {
      return this.tasks.filter((task) => task.completed === this.showDone);
    }
  },

  methods: {
    isCompleted() {
      this.showDone = true;
    },
    isPending() {
      this.showDone = false;
    }
  }
};
```

And in the template you can display the tasks like this:

```html
<tr v-for="task in getTasks" v-bind:key="task.id" v-bind:class="{showDone}">
```

**NB:** `v-bind:key` is required by *Vue* in `for` loops to make an item unique, so make sure to use an uniqe attribute of `task` in there.

Now clicking on the `li` tags you can toggle between completed and not completed tasks. Otherwise you can create two computed properties to get completed and uncompleted tasks separately in two tables.

```js
computed: {
  getCompletedTasks() {
    return this.tasks.filter((task) => task.completed);
  },
  getPendingTasks() {
    return this.tasks.filter((task) => !task.completed);
  }
},
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wave-mc4td) it is a working example with both the solutions.

Comment: When I do that everything disappears

Comment: `v-bind:class="{ isPending: !showDone }"` and you can continue using `isPending` class in your css

Comment: @Chibi check if `tasks` has elements and if its elements are done tasks or not

Comment: So if the task is done it will have a timestamp so it will always be unique. I don't know how to get that part so that I can then display it under 'Completed'

Comment: take a look at this example code i made, you can add how many properties you want to your tasks: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wave-mc4td)

Comment: Clicking on the `li` tags you can toggle between completed and not completed